# Keyboard's 'I' key stopped working

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I have a Microsoft Wireless 2000 keyboard, and recently the I key just doesn't work. Just that one. I took the plastic key out, and everything was fine in the inside. What could be the possible cause? Can keys simply die?

Comment: How did you type the "i"s in this message?

Comment: I used a replacemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My '*' key stopped working.](http://ask-leo.com/my_2_key_stopped_working_how_do_get_windows_to_recognize_it_again.html)

"Summary: Every so often a keyboard stops working or acts up. It's tempting to look everywhere but at the most likely culprit: the keyboard itself."

The above quote is from the site. Basically, it gives some common problems that may have caused your key to stop working for you to check and if not, then the keyboard is bad.

Comment: Well, this sucks. It's a great keyboard, and not too old. It only lasted 6 months.